# How to specify compilation flag in vs 2008 to turn off l1 cache in cuda

Tags: cuda, gpgpu, nvidia

I quote from the programming guide: 
Global memory accesses are cached. Using the –dlcm compilation flag, they can be configured at compile time to be cached in both L1 and L2 (-Xptxas -dlcm=ca) (this is the default setting) or in L2 only
 (-Xptxas -dlcm=cg).

I want to know exactly what I should change in VS 2008 to disable l1 cache. Please give specific instructions as this observation will be crucial. Is there a way to turn off L2 cache in CUDA too ?

Answer (score 1):

Go to your project properties. On the left click on Configuration Properties -> CUDA Runtime API -> GPU. There is a line labeled 'Extra Options'. Put whatever options you want to pass to nvcc there.

About a way to turn off L2 cache, there isn't one.

Comment: Should I put  (-Xptxas -dlcm=cg). or just  -Xptxas -dlcm=cg

Comment: The later, the parenthesis were used only to list the option in the middle of the paragraph.